# Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm having this problem in my project, and I've tried the solutions in this posts:
[Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899963/how-to-fix-22-0-1-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582664/android-studio-aapt-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1), but doesn't work for me. The project runs perfectly on 1.2 version of Android Studio, the problem started when I upgraded to version 1.3

Here is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.6'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.appname"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.applicationId
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.3.2"

    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.2.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'

    compile files('libs/android-smart-image-view-1.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"


}
```

the complete error is this:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':appName:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

In gradle console I have this errors:

> :appName:processDebugResources
>
> AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"simple","text":"/home/user/Desktop/projects/UMobile/trunk/uniforMobile/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png:
>   error: Duplicate file.","sources":[{}]}
>
> AGPBI:
>   {"kind":"simple","text":"/home/user/Desktop/projects/UMobile/trunk/uniforMobile/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png:
>   Original is here. The version qualifier may be
>   implied.","sources":[{}]}

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved!

I just renamed the mipmap folders with -v4 at the end.

Comment: Well done, but how did you get to that? Is there another answer you can link this too for example? Something people can get more info on the problem from.

Answer (score 0):

This is late but for my case I had deleted an image that was still being used.After re adding it and refreshing gradle all worked

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19043753)

Comment: @MauricioWanderleyMartins what link?